# Replacing a 'NULL' value in a CSV file with the date of today - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I am currently working on a Python project, that imports a data text file (CSV in my case) and then outputs the employees who have worked the most time together in a common project. First, this is the code and the data file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
from datetime import datetime
import csv

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("data.csv") as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # unpack use height as key and  append name age and position
    for EmpID, ProjectID, FromDate, ToDate in r:
        d[int(ProjectID)].append((EmpID, FromDate, ToDate))

for job, aref in d.items():
    if len(aref) >= 2:
        for ref in combinations(aref, 2):
            begin = max(map(lambda x: x[1], ref))
            end = min(map(lambda x: x[2], ref))
            delta = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d') \
                    - datetime.strptime(begin, '%Y-%m-%d')
            dd = delta.days
            if dd > 0:
                print('Employees with EmpID:', ref[0][0], 'and', ref[1][0],
                      'worked together on a common project (Project ID:', job, ') for a total of', dd, 'days')
```

And this is the data file, I am importing:

```
EmpID,ProjectID,DateFrom,DateTo
1,100,2014-11-01,2015-05-01
2,101,2013-12-06,2014-10-06
3,102,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
5,103,2014-10-01,2015-12-01
2,100,2013-03-07,2015-11-07
2,103,2015-07-09,2019-01-19
4,102,2013-11-13,2014-03-13
4,103,2016-02-14,2017-03-15
5,104,2014-03-15,2015-11-09
```

Now, I have a task that if there is a value 'NULL' in the 'DateTo' column, I have to make it equal today. I am thinking that there should be an automatic python function that gives the current date, and then do an if statement inside the CSV code block to replace 'NULL' with today's date (but it is only open in read mode as far as I know?). I would very much appreciate it if anyone can give me any tips! Thanks.

EDIT:
PANDAS PREVIOUS ATTEMPT FOR SOLUTION: (50% done)

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd'
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
# Read data from file 'filename.csv'
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later)
date_parser = lambda c: pd.to_datetime(c, format='%Y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter = ',', parse_dates=[2,3], date_parser=date_parser)
df.set_index("EmpID", inplace = True)
df.sort_values(['ProjectID'], inplace=True)
df['Days Worked'] = (df['DateTo'] - df['DateFrom']).dt.days
cutdown_projecs = df.groupby('ProjectID').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)

print(cutdown_projecs)
```

Comment: You need to read from that file and write to a second file, thus open 2 files

Comment: @jezrael I already tried a Pandas solution beforehand, I can show you my progress. I just wasn't familiar with the package and the operations I can do on the dataframe, so I decided to use traditional Python methods.

Comment: @jezrael Yes, all solved. Thanks.

Comment: @GerganZhekov - super, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

document = '''
EmpID,ProjectID,DateFrom,DateTo
1,100,2014-11-01,2015-05-01
2,101,2013-12-06,2014-10-06
3,102,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
5,103,2014-10-01,2015-12-01
2,100,2013-03-07,NULL
2,103,2015-07-09,2019-01-19
4,102,2013-11-13,2014-03-13
4,103,2016-02-14,2017-03-15
5,104,2014-03-15,2015-11-09'''

# df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(document))
df['DateTo'] = df['DateTo'].fillna(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print(df)

   EmpID  ProjectID    DateFrom      DateTo
0      1        100  2014-11-01  2015-05-01
1      2        101  2013-12-06  2014-10-06
2      3        102  2015-06-04  2017-09-04
3      5        103  2014-10-01  2015-12-01
4      2        100  2013-03-07  2019-05-30
5      2        103  2015-07-09  2019-01-19
6      4        102  2013-11-13  2014-03-13
7      4        103  2016-02-14  2017-03-15
8      5        104  2014-03-15  2015-11-09
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to use pandas to create this, and then export it again to a CSV (which would be a new one), that would be then opened from my code?

Comment: yes you can do that. depends on how you want to use it

Answer (score 2):

In your code is possible use `if-else` with condition for test empty values string values and replace by today datetime without times:

```
import pandas as pd

end = min(map(lambda x: x[2], ref))
end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d') if end != '' else pd.Timestamp("today").floor('d')
delta = end - datetime.strptime(begin, '%Y-%m-%d')
```